# is it possible to cast Dword to Type Name?

Tags: c++, dword

Let's take a look at this kind of code :

```
// Return me Dword of int
dword t = GetValueTypeNo<int>();
//here trying to tell to GetValue that my template is int (since t is dword of int)
int test5 = myVector.GetValue<t>("test5");
```

Of course this kind of code is not working and it's actually useless. But it is possible to do something like that? cast a `dword` to a type name like `int`?

Comment: You can definitely implement a function template `GetValueTypeNo` with each specialization returning some id and other template method `GetValue` using that id  without any problem.

Comment: @VTT I just tried to make a quick function comparing dword and returning typedef or typename (int by example) to see if it was possible but seems like GCC doesn't really like it ^^

Comment: Why not to use `GetValue<int>`? Why do you need a level of indirection? What are the constraints?

Comment: @Evg I'm just looking out to know if it's possible to do something like that.

Comment: If `GetValueTypeNo` can be marked as `constexpr`, it is definitely possible.

Comment: *"GCC doesn't really like it"* is not a problem description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `GetValueTypeNo` can be made a `constexpr` function, you can make something like this:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr dword GetValueTypeNo() { ... }

template<dword>
struct Type_selector;

template<>
struct Type_selector<dword_value_for_int> {
    using Type = int;
};

template<>
struct Type_selector<dword_value_for_long> {
    using Type = long;
};

...

template<dword type>
using Type = typename Type_selector<type>::Type;
```

and then write:

```
template<dword type>
Type<type> GetValue(...)
{ ... }

constexpr dword t = GetValueTypeNo<int>();
int test5 = myVector.GetValue<t>("test5");
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, it definetly respond my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `decltype` keyword:

```
dword t = GetValueTypeNo<int>();
int test5 = myVector.GetValue<decltype(t)>("test5");
```

But the here the template parameter of `GetValue` will be dword instead of int.

Comment: Using `decltype` in this context destroys the point because template specialization won't be selected based on type no.